# Blender file not slicing properly in Cura

Tags: ultimaker-cura, troubleshooting, blender

I need help with a blender file not slicing properly, the results seem very strange to me.    I'm pretty new to 3D printing, I have an ender 3 pro, using Cura for slicing.    I have been using blender for a few years, but only sporadically so i'm still somewhat of a novice.     I am trying to build a chain guard for an electric motorcycle, fairly simple cylinder with a cutout for the chain, a couple holes for bolts and my logo on the top.    I'm not having very good luck with the solidify modifier so i've traied duplicating the mesh and closing the faces to make it solid, still not working.

What I find strange about the slicing is that Cura builds all the supports correctly but doesnt print the cylinder, it also prints the logo fine.

My blend file is a mess, please help.

Thanks
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this work for sharing my .blend file?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vkpxfgvs0f7gy2g/Chain%20Cover7.blend?dl=0

Comment: It is not uncommon for Blender to produce STL files that have incorrect normals on the faces. Have you tried repairing the file through an online service like e.g. Netfabb?

Comment: That file is borked - it's blender's fault. Before exporting any blender file you need to Recalculate normals!

Comment: haha, yes it is borked.    I was able to re-draw and make it print ok but i will use recalculate normals in the future, thanks